# Subquery returned more than 1 value.

Tags: sql-server

i have query with this problem..
any people can help me?

this is my query

```
select t_tarif.lama, 
    t_tarif.id,
    t_tarif.kurir, 
    t_tarif.id_propd, 
    t_lokasi.propinsi as 'propinsi_asal', 
    t_tarif.kota_asal,
    t_tarif.id_propt,
    (select 
        t_lokasi.propinsi 
        from t_lokasi,t_tarif 
        where t_lokasi.id_prop =t_tarif.id_propt)as 'propinsi_tujuan',
    t_tarif.kota_tujuan, 
    t_tarif.tarif 
from t_tarif,t_lokasi 
where t_lokasi.id_prop = t_tarif.id_propd
```

Comment: YOu have used two sql antopatterns in your query, correlated subqueries and implicit joins. Suggest you read http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/ref=sr_1_cc_1?s=aps&ie=UTF8&qid=1339166836&sr=1-1-catcorr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this select:

```
(select t_lokasi.propinsi from t_lokasi,t_tarif where t_lokasi.id_prop =t_tarif.id_propt)
```

It can only return 1 value and it's returning more.

---

A possible solution is using `JOIN`:

```
select t.lama,
       t.id,
       t.kurir,
       t.id_propd,
       l.propinsi as 'propinsi_asal',
       t.kota_asal,
       t.id_propt,
       l2.propinsi as 'propinsi_tujuan',
       t.kota_tujuan,
       t.tarif
from t_tarif t
inner join t_lokasi on l.id_prop = t.id_propd
left outer join t_lokasi l2 on l2.id_prop = t.id_propt
```

I've used a left join to get the other clause because it seemed that's what you needed.

Comment: @Kartika check my solution, hope it helps!

Comment: i get error
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: It was missing the ON keyword, try the revised query

Comment: i get error again ... sorry for many ask to you 
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "l.id_prop" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "l.propinsi" could not be bound.

Comment: @aF. i think i know the error
thanks for help me...
HLGEM. thanks for help me too... :)